# index is not working while using ROW_NUMBER in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, non-clustered-index

I have used Row_Number() to implement the paging in my stored procedure. Paging is working fine. But problem is, after implementing the Row_Number(), indexes does not work & a Clustered index SCAN happens even if I use the primary key column in order by section.
below is the sample query:

```
SELECT TOP (@insPageSize) A.RowNum, A.AdID, A.AdTitle, A.AdFor, A.AdCondition, 
A.AdExpPrice, A.CreatedDate, A.ModifiedDate, A.AdUID
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vaa.AdID DESC) AS RowNum,
    vaa.AdID, vaa.AdTitle, vaa.CityID, vaa.AdFor, vaa.AdCondition, 
    vaa.AdExpPrice, vaa.CreatedDate, vaa.ModifiedDate, vaa.AdUID
FROM Catalogue.vwAvailableActiveAds vaa
WHERE vaa.CategoryID = @intCategoryID AND vaa.CountryCode = @chrCountryCode 
        AND vaa.CreatedDate > DATEADD(dd, -90, GETUTCDATE()) 
        AND vaa.StateID = @inbStateID AND vaa.CityID = @inbCityID
) A
WHERE A.RowNum > (@insPageSize * (@insPageNo - 1))
```

if I try to execute only inner query:

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vaa.AdID DESC) AS RowNum,
    vaa.AdID, vaa.AdTitle, vaa.CityID, vaa.AdFor, vaa.AdCondition, 
    vaa.AdExpPrice, vaa.CreatedDate, vaa.ModifiedDate, vaa.AdUID
FROM Catalogue.vwAvailableActiveAds vaa
WHERE vaa.CategoryID = @intCategoryID AND vaa.CountryCode = @chrCountryCode 
        AND vaa.CreatedDate > DATEADD(dd, -90, GETUTCDATE()) 
        AND vaa.StateID = @inbStateID AND vaa.CityID = @inbCityID
```

It does not use any index. AdID is primary key & there is another non clustered index which covers all where clause. But index scan occurs. If I remove the Row_Number() from inner query & check its execution plan, all indexes works fine but again StateID & CityID display as "predicate" while they are in non clustered index.

Please give me some guidance to solve my both  problems.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect, a seek? You are doing several things here that make it very difficult to perform a seek: (a) returning a RANGE of rows; (b) sorting to get ROW_NUMBER(), by AdID *DESC* - probably not the order your PK is defined; (c) filtering against something other than the PK, and (d) including many columns in the output that are unlikely covered by any NC index. A lot of people throw their hands in the air, yelling, "Oh my gosh! It's a scan! This is terrible!" Even in cases where, in fact, that's the most efficient way to do it.

(Just because a seek doesn't happen doesn't mean "indexes don't work" - it just means they probably would be even less efficient in satisfying this query.)

Comment: Hi Aaron,Thanks for your answer. I have created the non clustered index which covers all "where" columns & selected columns in "include" clause. If I ran above query without Row_Number, there is an  index seek.

Comment: @Anuj how do you expect to determine row number for every row in the table by performing only a seek? Think about that for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` is not using the index, because the data has to be filtered first.  And, this would seem to require a full table scan.  Or, at least, complicated combinations of indexes.

If you build an index on `vwAvailableActiveAds(CategoryId, COuntryCode, StateId, CityId, CreatedDate)` then it should use this index for the `where` clause.  The application of `row_number()` would still not use the index, but would presumably be on a much smaller set of data.

By the way, this assumes that the view is really just a select on an underlying table.  If the  query in the view is more complicated (even with a `where` clause, `join`, or `group by`), then that particular index might not be the best approach.

Comment: Hi Gordon, view contains data from 4 tables & in those tables is utilizing the clustered index seek. In my query, where clause contains filter only for the base table & my non clustered index sequence is : (categoryID, countrycode, createddate, stateID, cityID) include (title, adfor, condition, price, modifieddate). AdUid comes from second table which I have used in join & this table has a clustered index & It is utilizing its index seek.

Comment: @AnujRathi . . . You need to have `createddate` at the end of the list of fields.  It is used for an inequality in the `where` clause.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have also googled some other site, I think this will be a good option.